# Cant block specific ports for OpenVPN users

Tags: centos, iptables, vpn, openvpn

CentOS7.6 + iptables + OpenVPN2.4 (UDP proto) onboard.

Question is duplicated and seems simple: I just want to block some specific ports for my VPN users.
So I make

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p udp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m udp -m multiport --dports 445,3333,5228,17890 -j DROP
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

then do `iptables -L` and `FORWARD` chain contains my added rules.

Full iptables setup is:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 111.222.333.444
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -p udp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m udp -m multiport --dports 445,3333,5228,17890 -j DROP
```

But then I try to monitor traffic with

```
tcptrack -i eth0
```

I still can see that connections to blocked ports are creating.

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Idk why but this rule solves the issue

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 445,3333,5228,17890  -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that just because you've configured OpenVPN to use udp, doesn't prevent others from sending you tcp packets. Note the first rule you tried blocks only udp; the 2nd one that works blocks tcp.

As an aside, I prefer to use iptables -A rather than iptables -I so that the order in which I write my rules is the same as the order in which they execute. (iptables -L lists rules in execution order either way.) In my first (deleted) answer I got tripped up by your use of -I rather than -A, so interpreted your rule execution order backwards.

Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

Comment: [sf] is littered with questions where the use of `-A` added a rule after a `DROP all` or similar. In general you need to be aware of the rules in your tables and take appropriate action to place new rules in the correct place.

Comment: @Iain Fair enough. As you say, as long as you're aware of where your -I or -A places the rule, it doesn't matter which command you use. Still, I think it's easier to read your ruleset from top to bottom rather than the reverse. (Reasonable people may differ I suppose.) When I need to make changes to a chain, I prefer to simply flush it and reload the entire chain from top to bottom. If you have huge chains, you can often split them into one or more subchains that contain the frequently-updated parts, so that flush/complete reload is still practical. Or use an ipset when applicable.